# presentViewController doesn't work in ios 6

Tags: deprecated

I used the following code to switch to another xib:

-(IBAction)switchpage:(id)sender
{

JazzViewController *jazz = [[JazzViewController alloc] initWithNibName:"JazzWindow" bundle:nil];

jazz.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentModelViewController:jazz animated:YES];

}

changed it to this code for iOS 6:

-(IBAction)switchpage:(id)sender
{

JazzViewController *jazz = [[JazzViewController alloc] initWithNibName:"JazzWindow" bundle:nil];

jazz.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentViewController:jazz animated:YES completion:nil];

}

But it still doesn't work in IOS 6 (crashes back to Xcode with signal SIGBRT), 
it does work in iOS 5  en 5.1 at my simulator.
Anyone an idea of what I should do??

Comment: I resolved this. Seems that I had to make a new xib file and replace the old one. This is what I did:

Comment: 1. Rename header. For example  "mainclass.h" to "mainclass2.h"
2. Rename implementation. "mainclass.m" to "mainclass2.m".
3. Insert "File" => "New..." => "objective c-class". Select "UITableViewController" and create class with the original name ( mainclassViewController ).
4. Copy / Paste the code of header and implementation.
5. Delete old files.